# How can I search and replace a variable in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, regex

I have a bunch of files with lots of rows configured like this:

```
what,r-crq,What,What,VAC5700-035080,What
i,pns11,I,I,VAC5700-035090,I
do,vdd,did,did,VAC5700-035100,did
```

I want to do a search and replace to end up with this, storing and reinserting the 4 numbers after `VAC` and removing the trailing portion of the `VAC` number:

```
what,r-crq,What,What,VAC5700,What
i,pns11,I,I,VAC5700,I
do,vdd,did,did,VAC5700,did
```

Is there a way to do this for all the files at once (the `VAC` number will vary, so it needs to be stored as a variable), preferably in the Bash shell?

I assume I could also do this in “Notepad++” using regex, but I think the shell script would be preferable as I could do all the files as a batch.

Comment: You say, "the `VAC` number will vary, so it needs to be stored as a variable".  I don't understand.  I suspect that you're overthinking this — Steven's answer should do what you want.  (And, if it does, you should ***accept*** it.)  But, if his answer *doesn't* work for you, that suggests that you haven't explained your problem completely, correctly, and clearly.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's|,VAC\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)-[0-9]*,|,VAC\1,|' inFile > outFile
```

It will substitute `,VAC####-#...#,` with `,VAC####,`.